# How to tar multiple files without getting their paths

Tags: unix, tar

I was at a code interview which I failed, but I'm trying to understand it anyways.

From root, I was supposed to first get all html files and tar them on a single command.

After I failed, I was able to do it on my own like this:

```
find . -name "*.js" | xargs tar -cvf tar.tar
```

My problem is, it mimics the whole tree structure of the system. I wanted a solution that would put all the files on the same level, if I were to run on a folder with

```
-
 |  a.js
 |  b.html
 |  c.js
 |_ folder
   | g.html
```

My resulting tar ends up having a folder called `folder` with g.html in it. When ran from root, this looks terrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root@i5-cpu:~/work_area/php# tree d1

    d1
    ├── d2
    │   ├── f2_1.js
    │   └── f2_2.js
    ├── f1_1.js
    └── f1_2.js

1 directory, 4 files

root@i5-cpu:~/work_area/php# find . -name "\*.js" | xargs tar -cvf tar.tar --transform='s,.*/,,'

./d1/d2/f2_1.js
./d1/d2/f2_2.js
./d1/f1_1.js
./d1/f1_2.js

root@i5-cpu:~/work_area/php# tar -tvf tar.tar

-rw-rw-rw- root/root         0 2019-01-17 01:12 f2_1.js
-rw-rw-rw- root/root         0 2019-01-17 01:12 f2_2.js
-rw-rw-rw- root/root         0 2019-01-17 01:11 f1_1.js
-rw-rw-rw- root/root         0 2019-01-17 01:11 f1_2.js
```

Check this page https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_51.html 
The examples with **--transform**

Comment: I'm getting `tar: Option --transform=s,./,, is not supported` when I run this command

Comment: In my solution I was used the GNU tar flavor (the one available on most operating systems). Probable you have a freeBSD flavor, see https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/tar-option-transform-is-not-supported.54799/ . If yes, then you have to use _-s_ option. I can not test now (no freeBSD available) but based on the manual https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports , it should be    **-s /.\*\\///** (probable you have to play a little with escaping /). Please check that I've later edit the solution, couple of **\*** were not visible